# Why shouldn't I make api calls in getStaticProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I read in the nextJs docs that I shouldn't make api calls in the getStaticProps function. Can anyone explain with an example why?
According to the docs, it's because server-sided code can be directly written in getStaticProps. I don't quite get what that means. Something with an example would help.

Comment: I think it is just a suggestion. 
If you are retrieving data from your `/api` route, you should just extract the logic in your APIs into getStaticProps. This saves you some time when building your application.
If your API is from another server, you can still fetch it in getStaticProps.

Comment: If your api is from third party server, you can fetch in getStaticProps. Docs recommended not to make api calls (if it is from your own server) because it happens only in build time.

Comment: can I build a web app with just nextJs and server within itsself

Comment: @Needtocode sure you can

Comment: From the note on nextjs docs: "Fetching from an external API is fine!"

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are referring to this [NextJS Data Fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)

> Note: You should not use fetch() to call an API route in getServerSideProps. Instead, directly import the logic used inside your API route. You may need to slightly refactor your code for this approach.
> Fetching from an external API is fine!

This note is explicitly for API endpoints built into your NextJS app that would reside under the pages/api directory as described here [NextJS API Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)

They suggest moving the API logic into getServerSideProps instead of calling the API endpoint.